# Load function causes website to stall

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, settimeout

When I try to 'load' the 'saved drawing' by pressing 's' and then pressing 'l' it causes the browser to stop responding. I think it is because of all the while loops (line 47 and higher) but even the setTimeout things I added dont help. Help would be much appreciated.
This script is embedded in my website (https://veryblankwhitepaper.weebly.com/with-canvas.html):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("draw");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
var color = "#0000ff";
var xs = [];
var ys = [];
var colors = [];
var sizes = [];
var loadDrawing = function(){
    for(var p = 0; p < xs.length; p++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(xs[p], ys[p]);
            context.fillStyle = colors[p];
            context.arc(xs[p] - (sizes[p] / 2), ys[p] - (sizes[p] / 2), sizes[p], 0, Math.PI * 2);
            context.fill();
            context.closePath();
        },10);
    }
    alert("done!");
}
var isMouseDown = false; var thickness = 4;
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
} 
window.onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || e.which; 
    var key = e.which || e.keycode; 
    if(key === 65){
    color = prompt("Change the color");
    } 
    if(key === 76){
        if(confirm("Do you want to load a saved picture?") === true){
            var load = prompt("What file do you want to load","insert saved file name here");
            context.clearRect(0,0,100000,100000);
            alert("please wait. this may take some time depending on how big the drawing is..");
            xs = [];
            ys = [];
            colors = [];
            sizes = [];
            var int = 0;
            var str = "";
            while(localStorage[load + "xs"][int] !== ""){
                while(localStorage[load + "xs"][int] !== ","){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        str = str + localStorage[load + "xs"][int];
                        int = int + 1;
                    },10);
                }
                int = int + 1; 
                xs.push(str);
                str = "";
            }
            int = 0;
            while(localStorage[load + "ys"][int] !== ""){
                while(localStorage[load + "ys"][int] !== ","){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        str = str + localStorage[load + "ys"][int];
                        int = int + 1;
                    },10);
                }
                int = int + 1; 
                ys.push(str);
                str = "";
            }
            int = 0;
            while(localStorage[load + "colors"][int] !== ""){
                while(localStorage[load + "colors"][int] !== ","){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        str = str + localStorage[load + "colors"][int];
                        int = int + 1;
                    },10);
                }
                int = int + 1; 
                colors.push(str);
                str = "";
            }
            int = 0;
            while(localStorage[load + "sizes"][int] !== ""){
                while(localStorage[load + "sizes"][int] !== ","){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        str = str + localStorage[load + "sizes"][int];
                        int = int + 1;
                    },10);
                }
                int = int + 1; 
                sizes.push(str);
                str = "";
            }
            loadDrawing();
        }
    }
    if(key === 83){
        if(confirm("Do you want to save the drawing?") === true){
            var answer = prompt("Enter a name for the drawing.");
            localStorage[answer + "xs"] = xs;
            localStorage[answer + "ys"] = ys;
            localStorage[answer + "colors"] = colors;
            localStorage[answer + "sizes"] = sizes;
        }
    }
    if(key === 66){
        thickness = prompt("change thinkness (in pixels)");
    }
    if(key === 67){
        if(confirm("clear the canvas?") === true){
            context.clearRect(0,0,10000,10000);
       }
   }
}
window.onmousedown = function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
}
window.onmouseup = function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
}
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if(isMouseDown === true){
        xs.push(getMousePos(canvas, e).x);
        ys.push(getMousePos(canvas, e).y);
        colors.push(color);
        sizes.push(thickness);
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(getMousePos(canvas, e).x, getMousePos(canvas, e).y);
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.arc(getMousePos(canvas, e).x - (thickness / 2), getMousePos(canvas, e).y - (thickness / 2), thickness, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even while your *question* might be implied by your opening paragraph/title, it's still good to ask one. What's your question?

Comment: i have a couple questions: Can someone help me fix this? Why does it do this?

Comment: The structure of those `while` loops is completely broken and will just loop forever until you exhaust the timer resources.  Please add to your question what you are trying to accomplish with those `while` loops.  Whatever that is will have to be done a completely different way.

Comment: The while loops are supposed to get every single value from the localStorage string and turn it back to an array. so it gets items between commas and adds it to a list until item 'int' of the string is empty.

Comment: At any stage in the code, what do you expect the value of str to be given it is updated inside setTimeout() calls and referenced outside of them?

Comment: You might also want to use canvas.toDataURL() to get data for your storage object

Comment: I guess that might work, but the output of the urel is extremely complicated for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested new code**

It appears that your two `while` loops are just trying to break up a comma delimited string into its separated parts and put the result into an array.  If that's actually the case (something you have not yet described in your question), then you can just do this:

```
xs = localStorage[load + 'xs'].split(",");
```

So, if you have an input string that looks like this:

```
"aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd"
```

You will get an output array like this:

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]
```

If you have different input or expect different output, then please show us EXACTLY what a sample input and output look like.  Trying to reverse engineer flawed code makes it hard to figure out what the actual intent of the code is.

---

**Explanation of what's wrong with your current code**

This `while` loop code you have now is fundamentally flawed and causes an infinite loop.

```
       while(localStorage[load + "xs"][int] !== ""){
            while(localStorage[load + "xs"][int] !== ","){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    str = str + localStorage[load + "xs"][int];
                    int = int + 1;
                },10);
            }
            xs.push(str);
            str = "";
        }
```

The issue is this.  Javascript is an event driven language.  When you schedule a `setTimeout()` it registers a timer with the system and when that timer fires, it puts your timer callback in the Javascript event queue.  That event will ONLY get processed when the main thread of Javascript has finished.

In your specific case, your while loop just madly spins forever and `int` is not increased until the `setTimeout()` runs.  But the `setTimeout()` can't run until the `while` loop finishes.  So, since both are waiting on the other and the `while` loop is spinning hogging the main JS thread forever, you get an infinite loop.  That type of structure just can't ever work in Javascript.

Comment: Wow! Way less complicated!! Appreciate it!